# I want to view the desktop view of my website in the mobile site as well wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I have designed a website with elementor pro and hello elementor theme, I want to disable the responsive design so I can view the desktop site view in the mobile as well. Plese help me.

I tried, removing the viewport tag in my header.php file but it still doesn't work checked out many youtube tutorials didn't work out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This would be a bit difficult, since elementor adds CSS in the theme file AND in the module output (inline CSS). More importantly, **why** do you want to do this?

Comment: Because my clients needs the desktop view on the mobile as well, I explained him that this not a good practice yet he needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a plugin called "Mobile Switch" to show the desktop version of your website on mobile devices. To use this plugin, follow these steps:

1. Install and activate the "Mobile Switch" plugin on your WordPress site.
2. Go to Settings > Mobile Switch in the WordPress admin panel.
3. Select "Desktop" from the dropdown menu next to "Switch to".
4. Click on the "Save Changes" button to save your changes.

Now, when a user visits your website on a mobile device, they will see the desktop version of your website. Please note that this may not be the optimal viewing experience for mobile users, as the desktop version of your website may not be designed to be viewed on small screens.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you so much for responding, can you please share the plugin link please?